# Excel formula to define the last non-empty cell in a column in a sheet chosen by the user

Tags: excel, excel-formula

I have an Excel file with several sheets with data and I have a "main" sheet called summary.
To explain let say that in my workbook I have the four sheets : "summary",  "apple", "orange" and "lemon".
I organized the summary sheet so that by settings the value of cell B2 I can get the data from the other sheets. So if B2 = orange I have some data from the sheets "orange" and if I set B2 = lemon I get the same data from the sheet lemon.

What I am not able to do is to define a formula to get the last non empty cell in the selected sheet.

I found this formula in this forum to select the last non empty formula in a column:

```
=MAX((A:A<>"")*(ROW(A:A)))
```

What I would like to do is to edit this formula so that if

```
B2 = Orange
```

the formula becomes

```
=MAX((Orange!A:A<>"")*(ROW(Orange!A:A)))
```

and if

```
B2 = Apple
```

the formula becomes

```
=MAX((Apple!A:A<>"")*(ROW(Apple!A:A)))
```

I tried editing the formula by using INDIRECT

```
=MAX((INDIRECT("'"&$B$2&"'!A:A")<>"""")*(ROW(INDIRECT("'"&$B$2&"'!A:A"))))
```

but the result I get is always 1048576 (the last admissible row in my excel).

Can you please help me?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If the original *Array Formula* was :

```
=MAX((junk!A:A<>"")*ROW(junk!A:A))
```

and cell **B1** contained:

```
junk
```

then an equivalent *Array Formula* would be:

```
=MAX((INDIRECT(B1&"!"&"A:A")<>"")*(ROW(INDIRECT(B1&"!"&"A:A"))))
```

**Array formulas** must be entered with <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>Shift</kbd> + <kbd>Enter</kbd> rather than just the <kbd>Enter</kbd> key.